# Finding the Value of Words!

Tags: code-golf, string

## Introduction

In the land of [Insert cool name here], people don't buy things with money, because everyone has a severe allergy to paper. They pay eachother with words!
But how is that? Well, they give each letter number values:

```
a=1,b=2,c=3,etc.
```

(With some other special rules that will be described later)

In this challenge, your task will be to calculate the value of sentences.

## Challenge

You will take an input which will be a sentence. You may assume the input has no newlines or trailing spaces. The challenge will be to calculate the value of the sentence, using these rules:

```
a=1,b=2,c=3,etc.
```

- A capital letter is worth 1.5 times it's corresponding lowercase
  letter

`H=h*1.5`

So, the word

```
cab
```

Would be worth `c+a+b = 3+1+2 = 6`

But the word `Cab` with a capital c would be worth `(c*1.5)+a+b = 4.5+1+2 = 7.5`
So if your program input was "Cab" your program would output 7.5

- All non alphabetic characters are worth 1.

This is code golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins. Good luck!

Comment: Wait, money is *paper??* I always thought it was either shiny metal discs or some sort of magic invoked by swiping the sacred card.

Comment: Even U.S. banknotes are actually made of cotton and linen..but I guess the people of [Insert cool name here] hadn't thought of that yet.

Comment: Are trailing zeros allowed? E.g., printing `7.0` instead of `7`?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Trailing 0s are allowed.

Comment: What about spaces?

Comment: @juniorRubyist All non-alphabetic characters are worth 1.

Answer (score 13):

## Python 3, <s>71</s> <s>65</s> 61 bytes

```
lambda z:sum((ord(s)*1.5**(s<'_')-96)**s.isalpha()for s in z)
```

By an extraordinary coincidence, `(ord(s)-64)*1.5` is equal to `ord(s)*1.5-96`, so we only have to write `-96` once. The rest is pretty straight forward.

Edit: Shaved off some bytes using exponentiation shenanigans.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <strike>120</strike> 102 bytes

Edit:

```python
e=raw_input()
print sum([ord(l)-96for l in e if not l.isupper()]+[1.5*ord(l)-96for l in e if l.isupper()])
```

First submission, not so golfy but one has to start somewhere.

```python
def s2(p):
 c=0
 for l in p:
  if l.isupper():
   c+=(ord(l.lower())-96)*1.5
  else:
   c+=ord(l)-96
 return c
print s(raw_input())
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! [This post](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/20469) contains some tips for code golfing in Python that may help you better your score. You could start by decreasing the amount of whitespace.

Comment: In your second list comprehension why not replace (ord(l.lower())-96)*1.5 with 1.5*ord(l)-96. You know that l is upper so just work with that and multiply out to remove the parens(64*1.5=96).

Comment: You can also remove the space between a closing paren and `for` in the comprehensions.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you could make this even shorter by simply making it a lambda with `e` as a parameter that returns the result.

Comment: In the "comprehension" one ?

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <s>23</s> 20 bytes

```
sm|*hxGrdZ|}dG1.5 1z
```

[Live demo and test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%7C*hxGrdZ%7C%7DdG1.5+1z&input=Cab&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=Cab%0Acab%0Aca.b&debug=1)

### Explanation

```
 m                 z    For each input character
    hxGrdZ              Get the value of it's lowercase form, or 0 for non-alphabetic characters
   *      |}dG1.5       Multiply it by 1 if it's lowercase, 1.5 if uppercase
  |               1     If it's still zero, it's a non-alphabetic character, so use 1 as its value
s                       Sum of all the values
```

Quite a few creative uses of booleans values as integers here.

### 23-byte version:

```
sm+*hxGJrdZ|}dG1.5!}JGz
```

[Live demo and test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%2B*hxGJrdZ%7C%7DdG1.5!%7DJGz&input=Cab%0Acab%0Aca.b&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=Cab%0Acab%0Aca.b&debug=1)

Comment: This outputs the wrong thing for `.` (all non-alphabetic characters should be worth 1.)

Comment: @Mauris Fixed!!

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 63 bytes

```julia
s->sum(c->isalpha(c)?(64<c<91?1.5:1)*(c-(64<c<91?'@':'`')):1,s)
```

This simply sums an array constructed via a comprehension that loops over the characters in the input string and performs arithmetic on their codepoints.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function char_score(c::Char)
    (64 < c < 91 ? 1.5 : 1) * (c - (64 < c < 91 ? '@' : '`')) : 1
end

function sentence_value(s::String)
    sum(char_score, s)
end
```

Thanks to Glen O for fixing the approach.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stuck](http://kade-robertson.github.io/stuck/), <s>85</s> 43 Bytes

<s>Yeah yeah, I know, Python is shorter.. :P</s> I'm using the same logic as Tryth now, for the most part.

```
s_"str.isalpha"fgl;l-|0Gc"_91<1.5;^*96-":++
```

Explanation:

```
s_                                            # Take input & duplicate
  "str.isalpha"fg                             # Filter for only alpha chars, save
                 l;l-|                        # Determine number of symbols in start string
                      0Gc                     # Get saved string, convert to char array
                         "_91<1.5;^*96-":     # Logic to find score for each letter
                                         ++   # Sum the list of nums, add to # of symbols
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 101 bytes

```
v=0
for x in raw_input():v+=(ord(x.lower())-96)*(1.5 if ord(x)<96 else 1)if x.isalpha()else 1
print v
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 30 bytes

```
q:i91,64fm1.5f*32,5f-+1fe>f=:+
```

How this works (wow, I've never made one of these!):

```
   91,64fm1.5f*32,5f-+1fe>      Construct an array so that a[i] == score for chr(i)
q:i                             Read STDIN and convert to ASCII codes
                          f=    Index each from the array
                            :+  Sum the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>85</s> <s>82</s> <s>80</s> 67 bytes

I love quick & easy challenges like this. :)

```
t=>[...t].map(c=>u+=(v=parseInt(c,36)-9)>0?v*(c>'Z'||1.5):1,u=0)&&u
```

This works by interpreting each char as a base-36 number, multiplying it by 1 or 1.5 if it's greater than 9 (`a-z` or `A-Z`), and giving 1 instead if not. As always, suggestions welcome!

Comment: The 0 in charCodeAt is bot necessary

Comment: @vihan Didn't know that; thanks for the tip!

Comment: why not use `toString(36)`

Comment: @l4m2 I'm not sure how `.toString(36)` applies here. Do you mean something like `parseInt(c,36)`? Actually, that might be shorter...

Comment: You can save some bytes by going recursive and using 2/3 when parseInt returns NaN:  `([c,...t])=>c?(parseInt(c,36)-9||2/3)*(c>'Z'||1.5)+f(t):0`

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 168 bytes

Not really golfed yet, but a start:

```
fun(w:string)->w|>Seq.map(fun c->if Char.IsLetter c then (if Char.IsUpper(c) then (float)(Math.Abs(64-(int)c))*1.5 else (float)(Math.Abs(96-(int)c))) else 1.0)|>Seq.sum
```

Here a more readable version:

```
let calc (w : string) =
    w
    |> Seq.map (fun c -> if Char.IsLetter c then (if Char.IsUpper(c) then (float)(Math.Abs(64 - (int)c)) * 1.5 else (float)(Math.Abs (96 - (int)c))) else 1.0)
    |> Seq.sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 68 bytes

This takes advantage of the fact that characters are automatically casted to integers, and that boolean values can be summed as integers.

```
sum([t(t>96&t<132)-96,(t(t>64&t<91)-64)*1.5,t<65|(t>90&t<97)|t>122])
```

Answer (score 1):

## K, 30

```
+/1^(,/1 1.5*(.Q`a`A)!\:1+!26)
```

.

```
k)+/1^(,/1 1.5*(.Q`a`A)!\:1+!26)"Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"
349f
```

How it works:

`` .Q`a`A `` generates two lists of lowercase and uppercase letters

```
k).Q`a`A
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

`!:1+til 26`maps each letter in each list from 1 to 26

```
k)(.Q`a`A)!\:1+!26
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"!1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"!1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Multiply the first list by 1, the last by 1.5

```
k)1 1.5*(.Q`a`A)!\:1+!26
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"!1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26f
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"!1.5 3 4.5 6 7.5 9 10.5 12 13.5 15 16.5 18 19.5 21 22.5 24 25.5 27 28.5 30 31.5 33 34.5 36 37.5 39
```

Raze into a single dictionary using `,/`

```
k)(,/1 1.5*(.Q`a`A)!\:1+!26)
a| 1
b| 2
c| 3
d| 4
..
```

Map the characters in the input string  to the relevant scores

```
k)(,/1 1.5*(.Q`a`A)!\:1+!26)"Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"
24 18 15 7 18 1 13 13 9 14 7 0n 24 21 26 26 12 5 19 0n 0n 0n 4.5 15 4 5 0n 10.5 15 12 6
```

Fill any null values with 1

```
k)1^(,/1 1.5*(.Q`a`A)!\:1+!26)"Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"
24 18 15 7 18 1 13 13 9 14 7 1 24 21 26 26 12 5 19 1 1 1 4.5 15 4 5 1 10.5 15 12 6
```

Sum

```
k)+/1^(,/1 1.5*(.Q`a`A)!\:1+!26)"Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"
349f
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 121 bytes

```
l=process.argv[2].split(""),r=0;for(k in l)c=l[k],o=c.toLowerCase(),r+=(o.charCodeAt(0)-96)*(o===c?1:1.5);console.log(r);
```

call js file with node (node index.js "Cab")

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 77 bytes

```
@_=split//,$ARGV[0];$i+=(ord)*(/[a-z]/||/[A-Z]/*1.5||96/ord)-96for@_;print$i
```

Tested on `v5.20.2`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3: <strike>86</strike> 85 Bytes

```python
t=0
for c in input():k=ord(c)-64;t+=k*1.5if 0<k<27else k-32if 32<k<59else 1
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# 81 Bytes

```
decimal a(string i){return i.Sum(c=>c>64&&c<91?(c-64)*1.5m:c>96&&c<123?c-96:1m);}
```

Call with (LinqPad):

```
a("Hello World").Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 102 bytes

```
foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$c){$v=ord($c)-64;$s+=A<=$c&&$c<=Z?1.5*$v:(a<=$c&&$c<=z?$v-32:1);}echo$s;
```

Usage example:

```
$ php -d error_reporting=0 value.php cab
6
$ php -d error_reporting=0 value.php Cab
7.5
$ php -d error_reporting=0 value.php 'Programming Puzzles & Code Golf'
349
```

Nothing special in the algorithm. Each character from the first program's argument (`$argv[1]`) is checked against `A` and `Z` then `a` and `z` and counted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 108 Bytes

Decently competitive, I'm kinda surprised. Not too shabby for not having a compact Ternary operator.

#### Code:

```
$a=[char[]]$args[0];$a|%{$b=$_-64;If($b-in(1..26)){$c+=$b*1.5}ElseIf($b-in(33..58)){$c+=$b-32}Else{$c++}};$c
```

#### Explained:

```
$a=[char[]]$args[0]                # Take command-line input, cast as char array
$a|%{                              # For each letter in the array
  $b=$_-64                         # Set $b as the int value of the letter (implicit casting), minus offset
  If($b-in(1..26)){$c+=$b*1.5}     # If it's a capital, multiply by 1.5.
                         # Note that $c implicitly starts at 0 the first time through
  ElseIf($b-in(33..58)){$c+=$b-32} # Not a capital
  Else{$c++}                       # Not a letter
  }
$c                                 # Print out the sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 85 bytes

```
float f(char*s){return(*s-96)*!!islower(*s)+1.5*(*s-64)*!!isupper(*s)+(*++s?f(s):0);}
```

The `!!` before `islower` and `isupper` are necessary, because the boolean values returned by these functions  are not guaranteed to be `0` and `1` , true value was `1024` on my system indeed !

Answer (score 0):

## [Candy](https://github.com/dale6john/candy), <s>26</s> 22 bytes

<s>(~"a"<{A#64-2/3*|A#96-}h)Z</s>

Thanks to @Tryth for the factorization trick!

```
(~"a"<{A2/3*|A}#96-h)Z
```

Invokation is with the -I flag, as in `candy -I "Cab" -e $prg`

The code in it's long form is:

```
while     # loop while able to consume characters from stack
  peekA   # A gets stack to
  "a"
  less    # is pop() < "a"
  if
    pushA   # capitalized
    digit2
    div
    digit3
    mult
  else
    pushA   # lower case
  endif
  number
  digit9
  digit6
  sub
  popAddZ   # add pop() to counter register Z
endwhile
pushZ       # push Z onto stack as answer
```

Answer (score 0):

## Prolog (SWI), 101 bytes

**Code:**

```
X*Y:-X>64,X<91,Y is X*1.5-96;X>96,X<123,Y is X-96.
_*1.
p(L):-maplist(*,L,A),sumlist(A,B),write(B).
```

**Explained:**

```
X*Y:-X>64,X<91,       % When X is upper case
     Y is X*1.5-96    %      Y is 1.5 times charvalue starting at 1
     ;X>96,X<123,     % OR when X is lower case
     Y is X-96.       %      Y is charvalue starting at 1
_*1.                  % ELSE Y is 1
p(L):-maplist(*,L,A), % Get list of charvalues for all chars in string
      sumlist(A,B),   % Take sum of list
      write(B).       % Print
```

**Example:**

```
p(`Cab`).
7.5
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 75 bytes

```php
while(~$c=$argn[$i++])$r+=ctype_alpha($c)?ord($c)%32*(1+($c<a)/2):1;echo$r;
```

Run as pipe with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a80eaf71f74ecfb297011d65076c59ca2482a9a).

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.bytes.sum{_1>64&&_1<91?(_1-64)*1.5:_1-96}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3DXTtiquL9ZIqS1KL9YpLc6vjDe3MTNTU4g1tLA3tNeINdc1MNLUM9UytgExLs9paiL5VBQpu0UrOiUlKsRCBBQsgNAA)