# Alphabet Position Finder

Tags: code-golf, string, number

*Inspired by the [Codewars Kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/replace-with-alphabet-position/train/python).*

Your goal is to take an input string such as this one:

```
"'Twas a dark and stormy night..."
```

and return a string containing the position of each character in the alphabet, separated by spaces and ignoring non-alphabetical characters, like this:

```
"20 23 1 19 1 4 1 18 11 1 14 4 19 20 15 18 13 25 14 9 7 8 20"
```

For an additional challenge, you can replace any numerical characters in the original string with themselves + 27. For example, `"25"` would become `"29, 32"`. This is completely optional.

You must use 1-indexing (`'a'==1`, `'b'==2`, etc)

Additional rules:

- You must return a string, not an array.
- Trailing whitespace is OK.

The winner has the lowest byte count.

Good luck!

Comment: [closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55052/finding-the-value-of-words)

Comment: @TheoC Is that mandatory or not? It says we should ignore every non-letter but then that we should replace numerical characters?

Comment: @TheoC Why? The general consensus is that answers should be able to output in any reasonable format, as it may add too much bloat and make it unfair to languages who can join by spaces in a shorter way.

Comment: @TheoC Why don't you just allow both?

Comment: Can the input contain any of [\\]^_`  (ascii 91 to 96)?

Comment: 2.Separate question: can it contain any of {|}~ (ascii 123 to 126)?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is a decent challenge overall, but for next time you post a challenge, here are some things to keep in mind. 1) This challenge is pretty simple. I think it would be more interesting if the optional part was mandatory (note, don't change that part now, it's too late). 2) You're pretty restrictive about some arbitrary parts. Why not allow an array? It's our standards than [an array of characters **is** a string](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216/31716). I would recommend reading through [this thread](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8047/) for ideas.

Comment: Future notes: 1 and 0 indexing are usually one and the same, and both are usually allowed. Also, constraining output formats is frowned upon. If it's a list of values let the language decide the format. The challenge isn't about formatting output nor is it about shifting indices. Therefore, it shouldn't be a constraint when you could just allow languages to do what they'd do naturally and focus on the challenge intent.

Comment: Can the input contain any non-ascii characters like `Э`?

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), (5?) 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

<sup>Rightmost two bytes are output formatting</sup>

```
áÇ32%ðý
```

A port of [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165824/53748), but O5AB1E is more terse for the alphabet filtering.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8MLD7cZGqoc3HN77/796SHlisUKiQkpiUbZCYl6KQnFJflFupUJeZnpGiZ6eHgA)**

#### How?

```
áÇ32%ðý - take input implicitly
á       - filter keep alphabetical characters
 Ç      - to ordinals
  32    - thirty-two
    %   - modulo (vectorises)
     ð  - push a space character
      ý - join
```

Comment: Since OP want it to be printed split by spaces, a trailing `ðý` can be added. But since halve of the answers output lists I guess just leave it for now.

Comment: Ah. I have missed it in my answers...

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>82</s> <s>78</s> <s>72</s> <s>69</s> 62 bytes

```java
s->{for(int c:s)System.out.print(c>64&~-c%32<26?c%32+" ":"");}
```

-13 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7BagIxEIbvfYqfQG2CbA62eHDVUnrWi72VHqazq0bdRJJoWWT76tuxCjMM88N88@3oTMWu2vd8oJSwIOcvD4DzuY5r4hrL6wqcg6vAmrcUP7@QTClpJy2VMmXHWMJjhj4V88s6RC0E8CSZVZty3dhwyvYYJdQ8H78Mfgt@fB5NR@PX6xwqqIlSpuz68sY8nr4Pwryj/583oqZXWRgbMSBz8/KWtXr6@KEEQkVxD/KV3IXYtPBus83WWmVzeBfztxip1eYu3/V/)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->                    // Method with character-array parameter and no return-type
  for(int c:s)         //  Loop over its characters as integers
    System.out.print(  //   Print:
     c>64&~-c%32<26?   //    If the current character is a letter:
      c%32+" "         //     Print the position in the alphabet with a trailing space
     :                 //    Else:
      "");}            //     Print nothing
```

Comment: `s->s.chars().forEach(c->{if(c>64&~-c%32<26)System.out.print(c%32+" ");})` (72bytes).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks! And -3 more bytes by changing it to a ternary if. :)

Comment: `s->{for(int c:s)System.out.print(c>64&~-c%32<26?c%32+" ":"");}` (62 bytes) using a `char[]` as input instead of a `String`.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>55</s> 50 bytes

```r
cat(utf8ToInt(gsub("[^A-Za-z]","",scan(,"")))%%32)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKO0JM0iJN8zr0Qjvbg0SUMpOs5RNypRtypWSUdJSac4OTFPA8jQ1NRUVTU20vyvpB5SnliskKiQkliUrZCYl6JQXJJflFupkJeZnlGip6en9B8A)

Reads input from stdin, <s>converts to uppercase,</s> removes non-<s>uppercase</s> alphabetic letters, converts to code points, <s>subtracts to 64</s> mods by 32, and prints to stdout, separated by spaces.

*Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen for the golf!*

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKO0JM0iJN8zr0Qjvbg0SUMpOs5RNypRtypWSUdJSac4OTFPA8jQ1NRUVTU20vyvpB5SnliskKiQkliUrZCYl6JQXJJflFupkJeZnlGip6en9B8A)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen * facepalm * duh

Comment: I have added two comments(questions) to the question - depending on the answer there is an opportunity to golf this down to 46 or even 39 chars.

Comment: You can do 47 by using `[^A-z]`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>62</s> <s>60</s> 49 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king).
-8 bytes thanks to [pLOPeGG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72200/plopegg).

After these improvements, this answer is now similar to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165827/64121).

```python
print(*[ord(c)%32for c in input()if c.isalpha()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcIxDoAgDADAr3QxggODfMXNODQQpFELKTXG16OXq6/mwr73KsRqprVINMEOfk5FIADxv95qLCUIjhqeNaOxm@19XB5sgBBRDkCO0LTI9QLTntU59wE)

Comment: Oh, I guess `%32` works as well

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <strike>24, 20, 14</strike> 13 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Zacharý (and Mr. Xcoder)!

-6 bytes thanks to Adám!

-1 byte thanks to ngn!

```apl
⎕A⍳⎕A∩⍨≡819⌶⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHfVMdH/VuBlMdKx/1rnjUudDC0PJRz7ZHXYuAShTU1dVDyhOLFRIVUhKLshUS81IUikvyi3IrFfIy0zNK9PT01AE)

### Explanation:

```apl
        ≡819⌶⊢  - to uppercase
   ⎕A∩⍨         - intersect with the letters A-Z (args swapped to preserve the order)
   ⍳              - index in
⎕A               - the A-Z letters list
```

### My initial solution:

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <strike>24</strike> 20  bytes

```apl
{⍵/⍨27>⍵}⎕A⍳1(819⌶)⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSN6ke9W/Uf9a4wMrcDsmof9U11fNS72VDDwtDyUc82zUddizSBKhXU1dVDyhOLFRIVUhKLshUS81IUikvyi3IrFfIy0zNK9PT01AE)

### Explanation:

```apl
             ⍳           indices of     
              1(819⌶)⊢  the right argument (⊢) changed to uppercase
          ⎕A            in the list of uppercase letters
{⍵/⍨     }              copy (filter) those items from the list of indeces
     27>⍵               which are smaller than 27 (all non A-Z chars will have index 27)
```

Don't laugh at me, I'm new to APL :)

Comment: That's actually remarkably good for someone new to APL! You don't need the parentheses, they're assumed. Also,`{1(819⌶)⍵}` can be `1(819⌶)⊢`. Otherwise, amazing job! Hope you enjoy APL in the future!

Comment: @Zacharý Thanks! I hope so (I have some knowledge in J , I'm not totally new into array languages)

Comment: As Zachary noted, the parentheses are [assumed](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR71b9R/1rjAytwOyah/1TXV81LvZUMPC0PJRzzbNR12LgOoU1NXVQ8oTixUSFVISi7IVEvNSFIpL8otyKxXyMtMzSvT09NQB), so you needn't include them into the byte count, resulting in 20 bytes.

Comment: @Mr. Xcoder Oh, I thought it was about the inner ones. Thanks!

Comment: Galen, I was thinking of doing this challenge in J, but the verbosity of capitalizing or lowercasing  stopped me.  Would you mind proving an explanation of your solution... I'm curious if it can be translated to J?

Comment: @Jonah I added an explanation. You're right, capitalizing and the alphabet itself cost much more in J.

Comment: Nice job! You can save a byte by composing the `1` to the `819⌶` and save five by removing 27s directly: [`27~⍨⎕A⍳819⌶⍨∘1`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///38i87lHvikd9Ux0f9W62MLR81LMNxO@YYfg/7VHbhEe9fUA5T/9HXc2H1hs/apsI5AUHOQPJEA/P4P9pCurq6iHlicUKiQopiUXZCol5KQrFJflFuZUKeZnpGSV6enrqAA); or take the intersection with the alphabet: [`⎕A⍳⎕A∩⍨819⌶⍨∘1`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVMdHvZvBVMfKR70rLAwtH/VsAzIedcww/J/2qG3Co94@oLSn/6Ou5kPrjR@1TQTygoOcgWSIh2fw/zQFdXX1kPLEYoVEhZTEomyFxLwUheKS/KLcSoW8zPSMEj09PXUA)

Comment: @Adám Thanks, nice solutions! I should have found the first one by myself, because this is something that can be done the same way in J :)

Comment: @GalenIvanov Interesting that J lacks set operations so badly where Dyalog APL also has `A∪B`, `A∩B`, and `A~B`.

Comment: @Adám Yes, it's true. I'm only aware of `-.` (Less) - subtraction / difference. Intersection is achieved by ([-.-.)

Comment: @GalenIvanov And union would be `([,-.~)`

Comment: `819⌶⍨∘1` -> `≡819⌶⊢`, abusing the fact that the depth (≡) of a character vector is always 1

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>69</s> <s>55</s> 54 bytes

```javascript
t=>t.match(/[a-z]/gi).map(i=>parseInt(i,36)-9).join` `
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcixCsIwEADQX7mtCZh0EASHdHd3K0KPNE2vtrmQHIr@fPSNb8MXVl8oi0k8h7a4Jm4Qe6D4VfUjmu@jj6T/kRW5IWOp4ZZE0el80eaq7caUJpia51R5D3bnqBbV3d9YAWHG8gRMM1ThcnwgUVzFWttp3X4)

## Explanation :

```javascript
t =>                       // lambda function accepting a string as input
    t.match(/a-z/gi).      // returns all parts of string that match as an array 
        map(i=>            // map over that array with argument i 
            parseInt(i,36) // convert to base 36 
                - 9        // and subtract 9 from it
        ).                 // end map
        join` `            // convert to space separated string
```

---

11 bytes saved thanks to @Kevin

1 more bytes thanks to @Neil

---

You can add support for numericals for some additional bytes (thanks to @neil)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 62 bytes

```javascript
t=>t.match(/[^_\W]/g).map(i=>(parseInt(i,36)+26)%36+1).join` `
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dci7DsIgFADQX2ExhVRptAkb3d1NHHz1Biilj0sDNxq/Hj3jmeAN2aSw0QGjdWXQhXRHcgUyI29uz9f9@mi8@MfGg@74Bim7MxIP@1aJ@qTErlX1UcgpBuxZX0zEHBcnl@j5wKvLBzIDZiHNDNCyTDGtX4bBjySlrIQoPw)

Comment: -11 bytes by changing `a-z` to `A-Za-z` and `i.toLowerCase().charCodeAt()-96` to `i.charCodeAt()%32`

Comment: `parseInt(i,36)-9` saves another byte.

Comment: `.match(/[^_\W]/g).map(i=>(parseInt(i,36)+26)%36+1)` lets you support numbers, not sure if that's the best way though.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/), (45?) 55 bytes

<sup>11 bytes added to format the output, which also makes this incompatible with Python 3)</sup>

```python
lambda s:' '.join(`ord(c)%32`for c in s if c.isalpha())
```

Another port of my Jelly answer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxDsIgEAbg3af408QAC0PdTPoWjg49QeS0BcJdYvr0GL/9a4fmWuaRlvvYaH9EglwNjH9XLnatPdrgzpd5TbUjgAsEnBA8C20tk3Vu6FMUCyZz@5KAEKl/QCVCtPb9QOFXVu/9dGqdiyLZ/3DjBw)**

---

Non-formatted version (returning a list of integers):

```python
lambda s:[ord(c)%32for c in s if c.isalpha()]
```

Comment: It looks like OP is insisting on string output separated by spaces, unfortunately

Comment: Yep - I missed that on all my answers - one becomes so accustomed to the norms of the site!

Answer (score 2):

## Japt v2.0a0 `-S`, <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
r\L ¬®c uH
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=clxMIKyuYyB1SA==&input=IidUd2FzIGEgZGFyayBhbmQgc3Rvcm15IG5pZ2h0Li4uIgotUw==)

---

### Explanation

```
r              :Remove
 \L            :  Non-letter characters
    ¬          :Split to array
     ®         :Map
      c        :  Character code
        u      :  Modulo
         H     :  32
               :Implicitly join with spaces and output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), (7?) 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Rightmost byte is output formatting</sup>

```
fØẠO%32K
```

A full program accepting a string in Python format which prints the result to STDOUT

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/t8IyHuxb4qxobef///19JPaQ8sVghUSElsShbITEvRaG4JL8ot1IhLzM9o0RPT08JAA)**

#### How?

```
fØẠO%32K - Main Link: list of characters (created from the string input)
 ØẠ      - yield the alphabet = ['A','B',...,'Z','a','b',...,'z']
f        - filter keep (discard non alphabet characters)
   O     - ordinals          ('A':65, 'Z':90, 'a':97, 'z':122, etc.)
     32  - literal thirty-two
    %    - modulo            (65:1,   90':26,  97:1,  122:26,  etc.)
       K - join with spaces (makes a list of characters and integers)
         - implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>152</s> 117 bytes

-35 bytes thanks to *@Lynn*.

```
[N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve][S N
S _Duplicate_input][S S S T S S S S S N
_Push_32][T S T T   _Modulo][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S S S T  T   T   T   T   T   N
_Push_63][T S T S _Integer_divide][T    S S N
_Multiply][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   T   S T T   N
_Push_27][S T   S S T   N
_Copy_1st][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][T   S T S _Integer_divide][T    S S N
_Mulitply][N
T   S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][T N
S T _Print_as_number][S S S T   S S S S S N
_Push_32_space][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PU1JCoAwDDwnrxi8eOtr/ECwoiJWsYXi62uniiEZmCVJXtY0xdPGqRQFatdRiApEpHEIAU0hgk4tCvT0S9FXCkIub/KLKDeb@V9r31RL6fohW4TB27XBgkdMx7XfCOu8JOdc9wA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Start LOOP:
  Character c = STDIN as character
  Integer n = (c modulo-32) * (c integer-divided by 63)
  Integer m = 27 integer-divided by (n + 1) * n;
  If(m == 0):
    Go to next iteration of LOOP
  Else:
    Print n as integer to STDOUT
    Print a space to STDOUT
    Go to next iteration of LOOP
```

Comment: I don't have the time to write it in Whitespace, but maybe you could write something like [this](https://tio.run/##VY/BbsIwEETv/oopCGGH0EBAIJHCrVVv/YbIa4IlY0fGgUPVb09tUIFa8sHeebMzcipNbZu@H2orTUcKb6dA2r0edkzbAJmDcqiKsWOtLRf4Zsa5dsMAiS0aFeSh9lxUeDpF8TeIMr0Hj9It3r8@BLwKnbeYVXFC0YDL0aIUGZfFavkwiQbUtViUODrC6VK3WC1B@owscipy5brgNJmLjKr/ixOXbrm@cXNM7mCKolKUmUDjgkOqkpK0Pnbd88GIBrGvuH51t2ZjjK/vJ/1P338qY1yOi/OGXn4B)

Comment: Looks like that's [117 bytes](https://tio.run/##PU1JCoAwDDwnrxi8eOtr/ECwoiJWsYXi62uniiEZmCVJXtY0xdPGqRQFatdRiApEpHEIAU0hgk4tCvT0S9FXCkIub/KLKDeb@V9r31RL6fohW4TB27XBgkdMx7XfCOu8JOdc9wA)! (*I changed 64 to 63 in the code, as it's equivalent but shorter to represent in Whitespace) :)

Comment: @Lynn Not bad, -35 bytes right there. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>9</s> <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
üpÉÿ%}},√
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81709098257d7d2cfb&i=%22%27Twas+a+dark+and+stormy+night...%22&a=1)

*-1 byte thanks to @recursive*

Explanation:

```
v{VaIvm0-J Full program, unpacked, implicit input
v          Lowercase
 {    m    Map:
  VaI        Index in lowercase alphabet (0-based, -1 for not found)
     ^       Increment
       0-  Remove zeroes
         J Join by space
           Implicit output
```

#### [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
É▌Xl»↔"
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=90dd586caf1d22&i=%27Twas+a+dark+and+stormy+night...&a=1&m=2)

This one outputs newline-separated. Unpacked: `vmVaI^|c`. Similar, but with map, which implicitly outputs with trailing newline.

Comment: Hm. There appears to be a problem packing programs that end in space

Comment: @recursive Oh, didn't notice that (usually I try the links, but apparently I forgot it here). I added a workaround.

Comment: I never noticed this bug either.  I'll fix it in the next release of Stax.  Existing packed programs will remain unchanged.

Comment: [Here's a 9 back](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81709098257d7d2cfb&i=%22%27Twas+a+dark+and+stormy+night...%22&a=1) for your trouble.

Answer (score 2):

## x86 opcode, 35 bytes

```
0080h: AC 3C 24 75 04 88 45 FF C3 0C 20 2C 60 76 F1 D4
0090h: 0A 0D 30 30 86 E0 3C 30 74 01 AA 86 E0 AA B0 20
00a0h: AA EB DD                                       

f:  lodsb
    cmp al, '$'
    jnz @f
        mov [di-1], al
        ret
    @@:
    or al, 32
    sub al, 96
    jbe f
    aam
    or ax, 3030H
    xchg ah, al
    cmp al, 48
    jz @f
        stosb
    @@:
    xchg ah, al
    stosb
    mov al, 32
    stosb
    jmp f
```

Assuming the result contain at least one letter, and no `{|}~`

40 bytes, allowing all ASCII chars

```
0080h: AC 3C 24 75 04 88 45 FF C3 0C 20 2C 60 76 F1 3C
0090h: 1A 77 ED D4 0A 0D 30 30 86 E0 3C 30 74 01 AA 86
00a0h: E0 AA B0 20 AA EB D9
```

Comment: What's "x86 opcode"? Is this just an x86 machine code submission?

Comment: @Jakob true. I here don't say ".COM" cuz it's a function and don't rely on ".COM" format

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I think it's assumed that machine code solutions don't have to be complete executables. Might actually be better to just label it "x86 machine code"

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

Handles numbers as well

```
žKÃlvžKlÙyk>ðJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6D7vw805ZUAq5/DMymy7wxu8/v8PKTcpVkhUSEksylZIzEtRMC0xKMqtVMgzTM8o0dPTAwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
láÇ96-ðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/5/DCw@2WZrqHNxze@/@/ekh5YrFCokJKYlG2QmJeikJxSX5RbqVCXmZ6Romenh4A)

or, if we can return an array:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
láÇ96-
```

Explanation:

```
l         Lowercase
 á        Only letters
  Ç       Codepoints
   96-    Subtract 96.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/5/DCw@2WZrr//6uHlCcWKyQqpCQWZSsk5qUoFJfkF@VWKuRlpmeU6OnpAQA)

or if you want it to count numbers:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
lAžh«DŠÃSk>ðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP8wNWFiMWX//2xBxb5owqtExaDDg1NrPsOww73//ydUd2FzIGEgZGFyayBhbmQgc3Rvcm15IG5pZ2h0Li4uMjU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
≔⁺β⭆χιβＦ↧Ｓ¿№βι«Ｉ⊕⌕βι→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LczRCoIwGAXga32KH2/6ByZ1W1chBEGCVC/wO6eOdJNtKhE9@5rU5eF85/CODNfUe3@yVrYKy36yWKVwd0aqtqAR97sUJGMpVOwYN9oAXvUiDCcr8KLGyf0oMsZANoC5npRbL8II3nFUhtZhTtYFzo0YhHKixrNU9V@xcBwVehZ4uMm2cyF@vE82j4UsENRknkCqBuu0GV6gVpNlWRL77dx/AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁺β⭆χιβ
```

Append the digits to the predefined lowercase letters variable.

```
Ｆ↧Ｓ
```

Loop over the lowercased input.

```
¿№βι«
```

If the current character is a letter or digit,

```
Ｉ⊕⌕βι
```

print its 1-indexed index,

```
→
```

and leave a space for the next value.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 70 bytes

```php
for(;$c=$argv[1][$i++];)if(($c=ord($c))>64&($c%=32)>0&$c<27)echo"$c ";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVkm1VEovSy6INY6NVMrW1Y601M9M0NIDC@UUpQEpT087MRA3IULU1NtK0M1BTSbYxMtdMTc7IV1JJVlCy/m9v9/@/ekh5YrFCokJKYlG2QmJeikJxSX5RbqVCXmZ6Romenh4A)

-5 bytes thanks to Kevin

Comment: Snippets aren't allowed as submissions here, but you can make it a function or a full program.

Comment: Sorry, now it uses the first argument as input

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! If you haven't already, [tips for golfing in PHP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/tips-for-golfing-in-php) and [tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through. As for parts you can golf: `&&` can be `&`, and `ord(strtolower($c))-96` can be `ord($c)%32`. Also, I think you can remove the `~` before `$c`, but I'm not sure. Haven't programmed much in PHP, and don't really know what the `~` is used for right here anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Mod 32 is a good idea. It saves some bytes but requires an additional check to make sure ord($c) is bigger than 64.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 93 bytes

```
func[s][a: charset[#"a"-#"z"]parse lowercase s[any[copy c a(prin[-96 + to-char c""])| skip]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCsIwEEbhvaf4mS5UpF0K9hjibpjFkKS2VJOQpJSKd4929/jgJWfr3VmWw9DXYfGGs7D2MKOm7Ao3pNQ29CGJO@AVVpeM/iuz@o1NiBsM9BTT5Lm9XXFBCe2@wxDJ@Ys8T1FE6gA6PlbNUFhNM9Rb5BLSe4OfnmPpuo7qDw)

Comment: I don't know enough about Red, but can `#"a"-#"z"` be changed to both lower and uppercase letters; and then the `lowercase` can be removed; and `-96 + to-char c` can be modulo-32? Not sure if that even saves bytes In Red, though.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen Thanks, I'll try it later

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `parse` function collects strings even when the match is a single character, that's why I always need the `to-char`. For the uppercase letters I would need to add to the charset #"A"-#"Z", which spoils the gain (if any) from eliminating `lowercase`.

Comment: Yeah, I was kinda afraid `#"A"-#"Z"` might not gain much in comparison to `lowercase`, since it's only 1 byte shorter. And I knew you'd need the `to-char`, just wasn't sure if `-96 + ` and modulo-32 would be similar in size.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 47 bytes

With additional challenge of parsing digits:

```perl
print map{(ord(uc)-64)%43," "}<>=~/([A-Z\d])/gi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRCErPzNPSUFJJzexoFpDI78oRaE0WVPXzERT1cS41sbOtk5fI9pRNyomJVZTPz3z/3/1kPLEYoVEhZTEomyFxLwUheKS/KLcSoW8zPSMEj09PQA)

Reduced to 38 bytes by ignoring digits

```perl
print map{ord()%32," "}<>=~/([A-Z])/gi
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) 2.0 `-S`, 9 bytes

```
f\l ®c %H
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ZlxsIK5jICVI&input=IidUd2FzIGEgZGFyayBhbmQgc3Rvcm15IG5pZ2h0Li4uIgotUw==)

### Explanation:

```
f\l ®c %H                                    Input: "Hello..."
f            Match:
 \l             [A-Za-z]                     ["H","e","l","l","o"]
    ®        Map Z over the results:
     c         char-code of Z                [72,101,108,108,111]
       %H      mod 32                        [8,5,12,12,15]
-S           Join the chars with a space     8 5 12 12 15
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 35 bytes

```perl
$_="@{[map{(-64+ord uc)%43}/\w/g]}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbJoTo6N7GgWkPXzEQ7vyhFoTRZU9XEuFY/plw/PbZW6f//xKTklNS09IzMrOyc3Lz8gsKi4pLSsvKKyioDQyNjE1MzcwtLvX/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYAAA)

Includes the extra portion about the digits.

Comment: `/\w/` includes `_`

Comment: Much smaller than what I'd been playing with! You can save one byte, and fix the bug @BradGilbertb2gills mentioned, using `-F/[^0-9\pL]|/`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhN7FAX09fTU0jvyhFozRZU9fMRFPVxFhBT0VJx8Ht///EpOSU1LT0jMys7JzcvPyCwqLiktKy8orKKgNDI2MTUzNzC0u9f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7r5iW66UfHGehaxhT4xNboAwA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### PHP <strike>108</strike> 105 Bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##HY1BDoIwFET3nKJpTKhJKQdAJN7BlUbrj9TSWOjPbyOBy2N1lvPeZHDA7dDhgMUOyH5afp4hMmA90JvB1LOYAo0Lm5wdklKKN0V3zIs2Jkok3Ig@9EZwxmVudETvkvix4MNsSCAZq8mgh2e26uv9VF2gWm81l2Up/5/7HAlEsOiXdygIJpvdB5drJk2xbV8) (108 Bytes)

[Tri it online](https://tio.run/##HY1BDsIgFET3PQUhJsUE2wPU2kt0Z7T@CAKRws@H2LSXr@gs583LoMX9PKDF6gBkPj0fF0gMmAJ6MwiKpRxpXllwxuamaXhXDZdi9ClTJuFm9FFpwRmXpZkSepcFkjYTafTwLKi93uG03Vou6/o3ytHHRZP4Hx5LJBDBOr28Q0EQTHEeXG6FdPv@BQ) (105 Bytes)

-3 Bytes, thanks to @manassehkatz
  (Change the level of strtolower and remove A-Z from regex)

**Code, tried to avoid any loop**

```
<?=strtr(implode(" ",str_split(preg_replace(
"/[^a-z]/",'',strtolower($argv)))),array_flip(range("`",z)));
```

**Explanation**

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-z]/",'',strtolower($argv))  
//the string only contains letters

$string = implode(" ",str_split($string)); 
//the string has a space after every letter

$string = strtr($string, array_flip(range("`",z)));  
//replace every letter   acording to the array

$replacementArray = array_flip(range("`",z));
//this array contains the ansi characters from "`" to the "z"
//array_flip to change the keys with the values
//final array ["`"=>0,"a"=>1, "b"=>2...."z"=>26]
```

Comment: In order to get this to run without Warnings, I had to (a) change $argv to $argv[1] and (b) add " around the last z. But with or without those changes (which might be version dependent - I am using 5.6), you can save 3 bytes by moving the strtolower() in a level `strtolower($argv)` and remove capital `A-Z` from the regex.

Comment: On php 7 it trows a warning, im gonna modified the answer now. I am sorry just no wi had time to check :-D

Comment: @manassehkatz Taked your suggestion, and saved 3 Bytes, thanks a lot.

Comment: Shouldnt that be `$argv[1]` or `$argn` instead of `$argv`?. `join` is 3 bytes shorter than `implode`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 32 bytes (alpha), 41 bytes (alpha+digit)

```perl6
{~(.uc.comb(/<:L>/)».ord X-64)}
```

[Try it (32 bytes alpha)](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszcWVW6mglpyfkqpg@7@6TkOvNFkvOT83SUPfxsrHTl/z0G69/KIUhQhdMxPN2v/FiZUKILUaSuoh5YnFCokKKYlF2QqJeSkKxSX5RUCj8jLTM0r09PSUNPUKgDYBzYfrMTLFFFOPV4cK/gcA)

```perl6
{~((.uc.comb(/<:L+:N>/)».ord X-64)X%43)}
```

[Try it (41 bytes alpha + digit)](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszcWVW6mglpyfkqpg@7@6TkNDrzRZLzk/N0lD38bKR9vKz05f89BuvfyiFIUIXTMTzQhVE2PN2v/FiZUKIE0aSuoh5YnFCokKKYlF2QqJeSkKxSX5RUAz8zLTM0r09PSUNPUKgFYCLYLrMTLFFFOPV4cK/gcA)

### Expanded:

#### 32 bytes alpha

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter $_

  ~( # coerce to string (space separated)

      .uc                      # uppercase
      .comb( / <:L > / )\      # get letters as a sequence
      ».ord                    # get the ordinal of each
      X- 64                    # subtract 64 from each
  )
}
```

#### 41 bytes alpha + digit

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter $_

  ~( # coerce to string (space separated)
    (
      .uc                      # uppercase
      .comb( / <:L + :N > / )\ # get letters and numbers as a sequence
      ».ord                    # get the ordinal of each
      X- 64                    # subtract 64 from each
    ) X% 43                    # modulus 43 for each
  )
}
```

Comment: This also matches non-ASCII characters like `Э`, but I've asked for clarification from the OP on whether the input is ASCII-only or not.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 93 bytes

```
puts [lmap c [split $argv ""] {if [string is alp $c] {expr ([scan $c %c]-64)%32} {continue}}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDsIgEAXQq/w0bdSFLNR4EneExWRakUgpgWnVNJwd2b7kCfta4yoZ2s8UwdA5eifoKdkNXWewu2dDSS5YuAzyET03nr4x4agzU2iAgc35fjsN10vBzksQF9apFFNrPTw@1CJGSm9QGJFlSfMPwdmXKKX@)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <strike>[110 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#a%3D%22abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%22%3B%20print%20%22%20%22.join%28%5Bstr%28a.index%28l%29%20%2B%201%29%20for%20l%20in%20list%28input%28%29.lower%28%29%29%20if%20l%20in%20a%5D%29)</strike> [104 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#a%3D%22abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%22%3Bprint%22%20%22.join%28%5Bstr%28a.index%28l%29%2B1%29for%20l%20in%20list%28input%28%29.lower%28%29%29if%20l%20in%20a%5D%29), with user input

```
a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";print" ".join(str(a.index(l)+1)for l in list(input().lower())if l in a)
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##JclBDsIgEADAr2y4CDEh0avxF35gFdpuSxdcttL6eTw41ymHTpmvvePd4PMV4jBONC9p5VzeUnX7tP34mlsRYjVg/JyJbVWx6IlD3G1y54sbskACYkhU1RKXTa3zKbco1jka/omud3N6NKyAEFAWQA5QNct6ANM4qffe/AA)

---

## Python 2, <strike>[105 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#a%3D%22abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%22%3B%20return%20%22%20%22.join%28%5Bstr%28a.index%28l%29%20%2B%201%29%20for%20l%20in%20list%28t.lower%28%29%29%20if%20l%20in%20a%5D%29) [104 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#a%3D%22abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%22%3B%20print%20%22%20%22.join%28%5Bstr%28a.index%28l%29%20%2B%201%29%20for%20l%20in%20list%28t.lower%28%29%29%20if%20l%20in%20a%5D%29)</strike> [96 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#a%3D%22abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%22%3Bprint%22%20%22.join%28str%28a.index%28l%29%2B1%29for%20l%20in%20list%28t.lower%28%29%29if%20l%20in%20a%29), where `t` is predefined:

```
a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";print" ".join(str(a.index(l)+1)for l in list(t.lower())if l in a)
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##Jcg7DsIwEAXAqzy5wRaSJWhRbkGHKBaczybOOtgLSbi8KZhyll2HJOeqaGAO15UKCIHyBJKAoinPO4T7Qb33plJj6PEMbdcPPE5xlrS8ctH3Z932r7lgySwKA@PHxGJvRbMlzxLazUaHI04OXcqIYEHkolZ9TGubrXPg7v90d7X@AA)

Let's break it down with a more readable version:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
foo = [str(alphabet.index(letter) + 1) for letter in list(t.lower()) if letter in alphabet]
print " ".join(foo)
```

First, we define `alphabet` as being, well, the alphabet.

Next, we use list comprehension to:

1. Make a list where each item is a lowercase character from `t`
2. For each letter, if it is not in the alphabet, discard it.
3. If it is, find its index in the alphabet,
4. add one to it (because we start counting at 1)
5. and make it a string.

Finally, we join it all together and print it.

---

**Edit:** Changed to `print` (and lost portability) to save bytes and make it work outside a function

**Edit 2:** Added a version with `input()` instead of predefined variables

**Edit 3:** Removed 8 bytes in Solutions 1 and 2 thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

Comment: You've got 6 extraneous spaces in your code

Comment: @JoKing I found three (after semicolon, surrounding `+`), where are the others?

Comment: Before `if`,`for` and `" "`

Comment: You can also remove the `[]` in the `join`

Comment: Again, welcome to PPCG! FYI by default (i.e. if not explicitly overridden in the question) answer submissions may be functions or full-programs (like your 104 byte version) but not snippets (like your 96 byte version). Here you could submit a version which [creates a function which returns the string](https://tio.run/##JcixDsIgEADQ3a@4sAjRkOho0r9wdLkKtNfSo8LVtv48xvjGN@/SJ77W0DxqxKl1COWMjcL26XzoehrGOHGaX7nI8l63/aNuCpQdErEukjVaYuc3Hc3pYkLKEIEYIhXRxca0@qyNofBvNFV8kYZ4XkSbw5yJBYL@panqeF@xAILDPAKygyIpTzswdb1Ya9UX) for 100 bytes :)

Comment: `a.index()` is the same as `a.find()` in this context for -1 byte. Also `str(...)` can be replaced by backticks: `\`a.find(l)+1\``.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 84 bytes

```python
print(*filter(int,['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.find(c)+1for c in input().lower()]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBDsIgEEDRq8wOUENivIo74wKhFCwdcDot4uWR5C/e6pfGIeOt90IRWZ58TDyRHL48hHlZN/k5xPeSVszlQxvvR/22n9A@opNWna8@E1iIOCo7S6VTruOgnkr1Lu7VbGDAGVrAoIONM60NMM6BtdZ/)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 63 bytes

```powershell
"$(([char[]]"$args".ToUpper()|%{$_-($_,64)[$_-in65..90]})-ne0)"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBCsIwEADAryxLxATs0oMW/Ed7CqEsNjTFmoRNoYj69tjbnCan3UsJfl1rRaW1fQQW6xwqlrkg9WnI2Ys239NHjY1W46W7Gntwid2N6N66n2mibw3WYzj3OxdgmFiewHGCsiV5vSEuc9iICP8)

*(Seems long ...)*

Takes input `$args`, converts it `.ToUpper`case, casts it as a `char`-array, feeds that into a `for each` loop. Inside the loop, we subtract either itself or 64 from the (ASCII int) value, based on whether or not the current value is `-in` the range `65` to `90` (i.e., it's an ASCII capital letter). Those values are left on the pipeline, and we use a `-n`ot`e`qual to eliminate the non-letter values (because they're all zero). Those numbers are encapsulated in a string as the default stringification of an array is to space-separate it, so we get that pretty cheaply. That string is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

## MS-SQL, 133 bytes

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(ASCII(substring(upper(s),number+1,1))-64,' ')FROM
spt_values,t WHERE type='P'AND substring(s,number+1,1)LIKE'[a-z]'
```

[Per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341), input is taken via a pre-existing table **t** with varchar field **s**.

SQL 2017 or later is required. Must also be run in the `master` database, because I'm taking advantage of a system table called `spt_values`, which (when filtered by `type='P'`) contains counting numbers from 0 to 2047.

Basically I'm joining a number table with the input string using `SUBSTRING()`, which returns a separate row for each individual character. This is filtered for only letters using `LIKE'[a-z]'`, then we get their ASCII value and subtract 64. These numbers are joined back into a string using the (new to SQL 2017) function `STRING_AGG`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
jdfTmhxGr0
```

I'm pretty sure this can be golfed a little bit...
-2 bytes if I can output as a list, some answers seem to but it's not in the spec

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyslLSQ3o8K9yOD/fyX1kPLEYoVEhZTEomyFxLwUheKS/KLcSoW8zPSMEj09PSUA)

Comment: You can remove the last `d` (`jdfTmhGr0`, 10 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.scan(/\p{L}/).map{|i|i.ord%32}*' '}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYpLCsIwEED3nmKoSFU0BV3rCbxBrTqmUww0HzKpUNKcPRYXunwfPzzH3J3y/syRBUs06@rq4iVVG6HRxUlNSljfro6HtC2hTNlBVxetJTZlAI1BvuBeV83tAWhGbT0VzeL/hO/xK7AEdiQV9jBbjzKQZ/Ck7ZvaHTBqmomHPuQP)

Comment: [A-z] is too wide, it includes underscores and other stuff.

Comment: @GB fixed at no extra cost

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 67 bytes

```c
c;f(char*s){for(;*s;)(c=tolower(*s++)-96)>0&c<27&&printf("%d ",c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctRCgIhEADQqwxCNrqtRB9FWJ2iCwxj7i61GqOwRHR2q//3uB@YW2MfkUcSW8w7ZkFvizfI55ofebkJ2tJ1pj/uzWWr@bQ7aP2UKdWIahVAbdj4T5tpSvjrqNbXhQoQBJI7UApQapb5BWkaxuqcU3/@BQ)

Converts each char to lowercase, offsets its code by -96 and, if it falls in the range of the 1-indexed alphabet, prints the offset code

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 45 bytes

```
[gsub("\\W";"")|explode[]%32|@text]|join(" ")
```

---

```
 gsub("\\W";"")                                # remove non-alpha characters
               |explode[]                      # get decimal values of characters
                         %32                   # get positions in alphabet
                            |@text             # convert back to string
[                                 ]|join(" ")  # join with a space
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z86vbg0SUMpJiZcyVpJSbMmtaIgJz8lNTpW1dioxqEktaIktiYrPzNPQ0lBSfP/fyX1kPLEYoVEhZTEomyFxLwUheKS/KLcSoW8zPSMEj09PaV/@QUlmfl5xf91iwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)], <strike>57</strike> 56 bytes (printing), <strike>70</strike> 69 bytes (printing w/optional), 146 bytes (string)

Thanks to ceilingcat for the `&&` optimization.

```
f(char*s){for(;*s;s++)isalpha(*s)&&printf("%d ",*s&31);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcxBC4IwGMbxu5/ipci2aQPpuPBTdIsOL5vTkU7ZliHiZ1@zS7c/vwceeWmljEdjZf9WDdx8UGbkXZ39SYZlahJFTWSHjnm66tERwbzwRUGNx37qkCTP88kZGzQ5nBQcSubza0XFFpPBgMaSPdC1styPgLHUM4U1AzCa7ENdUfjV/KieVGRbjOf7Bz0gKHQvQKvAh9ENC1jTdoFz/gU)

This version takes alphanumeric text per the additional challenge:

```c
f(char*s){for(;*s;s++)isalnum(*s)&&printf("%d ",(*s<65)*10+(*s&31));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcxBDoIwEIXhPaeYaMS2KLEibiCcwp1x0bQWGqGQtmAM4ey1uHH355uX4ceac79VmrejeEJpnVB92lTRn7j7DM9AXiLeMEMsnmVvUEFsYZMEK8taPXYoeBwPRmkn0WYnYHMIVF5zTOgpCRlnFONi8WEAHVMarcFMzQ/rVyAk9IRhjgCUROuhohh@Nd3pAxfR4v3@9mYWGAhmXsC0AOt6031Aq7pxaZoCPWeX/As)

If returning a string is required for this challenge:

```c
char*f(s,t,u,i)char*s,*t,*u;{for(i=strlen(s)*4,t=calloc(i,2),u=t+i;*s;s++)isalnum(*s)?sprintf(u,"%d ",(*s<65)*10+(*s&31)),strcat(t,u):0;return t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NTsMwEITveYpVEeB1TNT0hwNuyktwQxyM82fhOJG9LqqqPntweiu3mW81O6NfOq3nB@O0jXUDh0C1GYv@mN0ha77/M29cd880nacmoVn3yvOWBUEiCoM3GwQnwaO8tKNnpkp52zgWkO8EVVpZO2pmxAZFrCg3kgcZ8hxNUNbFgfGA72FKldSyKFaPNaxEgofXPfJynSf5tC0RRXqrFbHUi29r6RuK3gHJ65ySMCjj2CKU77RYVgHnSZ8QLhmAadlyOJYIU6TAbvb0WX4hyuw6z88fvyqAglr5H1CuhkCjH87gTNdTURRQbra7/R8)

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>23</s> 15 bytes

```
qel_eu-{i32%S}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzA1Jz61VLc609hINbhW//9/9ZDyxGKFRIWUxKJshcS8FIXikvyi3EqFvMz0jBI9PT0A)

Saved 8 bytes thanks to Esolanging Fruit

Comment: [`q{el_eu-},{i32%S}/`](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7A6NSc@tVS3Vqc609hINbhW//9/9ZDyxGKFRIWUxKJshcS8FIXikvyi3EqFvMz0jBI9PT0A "CJam – Try It Online") works.

Comment: Nice solution! I managed to golf it down a bit more

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 61 bytes

works in any PHP version from 4.0.4 to 7.2 (but might cease to work in 7.3)

```php
while(~$c=$argn[$i++])ctype_alpha($c)&&print(ord($c)&31)." ";
```

Run as pipe with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa40f4f063bf435a1886e57ced7fdf29b144a695).

Answer (score 0):

### [ABAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABAP), 228 bytes, letters only

I wrote a FORM subroutine for an ABAP report. i is input, o is output.

```
FORM h USING i o.TRANSLATE i TO UPPER CASE.DO strlen( i ) TIMES.data c(2).c = sy-index - 1.FIND i+c(1) IN 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' RESULTS data(r).CHECK sy-subrc = 0.c = r-offset + 1.CONCATENATE o c ` ` INTO o.ENDDO.ENDFORM.
```

Verbose code:
[Look at it on Pastebin.com for syntax highlighting.](https://pastebin.com/ndNv0ZU3) (Not that it looks much better)

```
"This stuff is used to actually run the program, call the form and output the results.
REPORT z.
PARAMETERS se_input TYPE string.
START-OF-SELECTION.
    DATA ret type string.
    PERFORM h USING se_input ret.
    WRITE ret.

"---- CODE STARTS HERE ----
FORM f USING i o.              "Two parameters: i for input, o for output.
    TRANSLATE i TO UPPER CASE. "All to uppercase
    DO strlen( i ) TIMES.      "Do for each character
        data c(2).             "A char field, length of 2
        c = sy-index - 1.      "Current loop index - 1 = index in string. Loop index starts at 1.
        FIND i+c(1)            "Find substring: input at position index, length 1...
         IN 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' RESULTS data(r). "...in the alphabet, save to "r"
        CHECK sy-subrc = 0.    "sy-subrc <> 0 => not in the alphabet, skips the rest of this loop (same as CONTINUE)
        c = r-offset + 1.      "r-offset is the index in the string, add one for alphabet position
        CONCATENATE o c ` ` INTO o. "Concatenate it all into the output chars, including the literal space.
                  "      ^- had I used ' ' here, CONCATENATE would remove blank space, but ` ` stays untouched.
    ENDDO. "Loop end
ENDFORM.   "FORM end
```

#### Notes, thoughts, background stuff

First of all, no, I did not miss spaces in my code. ABAP wants them and will not run without them...

The USING parameters i and o are of unknown type, so the program calling the FORM must use a string (or char field with at least `length of input * 3`: 2 characters + space per letter) for o, otherwise results can be cut off or it all just dumps right away if it's a numeric value for example.

I saved a few bytes here by re-using the same character field over and over again, abusing the fact that ABAP implicitly converts numbers to chars and vice versa without any issues. This is especially better than using the `CONDENSE <var>` statement, which was initially necessary to not have my integers padded to 26 characters width.

Getting substrings in ABAP is super quick and easy once you get used to it:
`substring = string+offset(length).`
Thanks to the implicit conversion, `offset` can be even a character field. Nasty, but great for us in this case. But be careful: While `string+5` gives you the substring starting from index 5, `string + 5` will try to cast your string to a number and add 5. Spaces matter!

There's also an easy way to convert the character to a byte value, giving me the ASCII code and removing the need to do the lengthy `FIND IN ...` stuff, but on a *Unicode* SAP system there's no quick and dirty way to convert that byte value into a "readable" number that I know of, so it's kind of a red herring.

By the way: `TRANSLATE i TO UPPER CASE.` is exactly 26 bytes long, so at first glance it looks like we don't even need it and can just add the lowercase letters to the alphabet string instead. But you probably realized right away why we *can't* do that. ;-)

---

#### Bonus:

### ABAP, 238 bytes, alphanumeric

For the alphanumeric version we just add 0123456789 to the alphabet string, hence increasing the length of the code by 10 bytes. Not very interesting, but any other approach would just be longer thanks to the very, uhm, *verbose* language that ABAP is.

```
FORM h USING i o.TRANSLATE i TO UPPER CASE.DO strlen( i ) TIMES.data c(2).c = sy-index - 1.FIND i+c(1) IN 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789' RESULTS data(r).CHECK sy-subrc = 0.c = r-offset + 1.CONCATENATE o c ` ` INTO o.ENDDO.ENDFORM.
```

---

I hope my explanation is somewhat interesting. Thanks for the challenge!

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 63 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char
unwords.map(show.(`mod`32).ord).filter isAlpha
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY49SwNREEX7/RWX3cKk2Cm0lBRLlIAESaF9hry3eUPex/JmwiLib1@jWNhezjncwHrxMS6ffYf98Lp7H3bP2B4O6Pqvpul7vFzViAhyzqV6WBClpnN@lOxxzXOpTiFpKtXwxMa0F7XHcSPZfD1xZPMt2uU/sQ1cmz@VEk8rDWWm1TEVd3y4X9NtX9Mo8RaA6BCnwEtiydjgt8onw7i0d28zKxiO6wWcHdRKTR/Icg4/l9tv)

Comment: Currently this only converts uppercase letters, you need `isAlpha` instead of `isUpper`.

Comment: @Laikoni I don't know how I failed to notice that...

Comment: 62 bytes and a less insane header: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdNCsIwEAbQvaf4KIIKNgvd2oXoEdwVF0PSmtD8lJmRIHj36Ns9T7JMMbYW0lpYcSclc/PEmxkyvHMt7GQUX@o2Fbf/D/ZwPn3tpZdjkGtcPcE@W6KQMSBknZisYm7d7lFJQHDECyg7iBZOH@Tw8mqM6X4 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 97 bytes

```ruby
n=[];gets.chomp.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/,'').upcase.bytes.each{|i|n.push i-64};puts n.map(&:to_i).join" "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDsIgEADAr2x6kDaR7cV4sPHgHzzZVLNtSUFTICzEoPXtOBPSmEux537oFhUZJ@1WjwunsW77O8nPRd6Gdi9Eg8lPxArHHBWjokl/N7NZ9Ik1GHk8/DqfIoPFlXy9O0X3MA0@nbEVVKWI65sYCGYKLyA7A0cX1gzWLDoi4h8)

Answer (score 0):

## Lua (5.3), 94 bytes

`x=...y=""for i=1,#x do z=x:sub(i,i)y=y..(z:find"%a"and(z:byte()&~32)-64 .." "or"")end print(y)`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc1NCsIwEEDhqwwjagJ1wB9cFHILLzAlrQ5qIkmKnS68eszyLT7ea@ZaF0dE6hCnmEDcsdss4COsbunzPBjpxKpTIrP2kwSPW0YOvtWgZTR29zuf7OF6ASIEjAnRjsHDJ0koRm2tFfe3L2dg8Jye0CzkEtNbIcj9Udoc/w)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `Ṡ`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ỊÄ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCQiU4QSVDMyU4NCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSUyMidUd2FzJTIwYSUyMGRhcmslMjBhbmQlMjBzdG9ybXklMjBuaWdodC4uLiUyMiZmbGFncz0lRTElQjklQTA=)

##### Explanation

```python
    # Implicit input
Ị   # Keep only alphabetic characters
 Ä  # And get the 1-based indices in the alphabet
    # Implicit output, joined by spaces
```